# Convert text into date format in Visual Studio 2013 using C# and save it in SQL Server 2014

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014-express

I want to convert text into date format in Visual Studio 2013 by using C#. Alas! I am getting difficulties in it. I also want to save this data in SQL Server 2014.

My code is

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText= "insert into Optical values('"+date.Text+"','"+name.Text+"','"+guardian.Text+"','"+gender.Text+"','"+age.Text+"','"+address.Text+"','"+occupation.Text+"','"+telephone.Text
                +"','"+sph.Text+"','"+cyl.Text+"','"+axis.Text+"','"+prism.Text+"','"+lsph.Text+"','"+lcyl.Text+"','"+laxis.Text+"','"+lprism.Text+"','"+note.Text+"')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();
        }
```

I want to change just date's text into date format. Please anybody guide me, how can I do it?

Comment: How does your `date` Text looks like? You could use `DateTime.ParseExact` to convert it to `DateTime` then you can re-convert it to `string` with the format which you want. How does it look like?

Comment: Use a [parametrized insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163361/how-can-i-add-user-supplied-input-to-an-sql-statement) - you have an SQL Injection vulnerability, put a `'` in `note` and see what happens.  This would also allow you to pass in a DateTime directly.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what "difficulties" you are having?  If you are getting exceptions please include them, or describe what results you get and how they differ from what you want.

Comment: @Alex K, If I would like to use parametrized insertion then what should I do in my code, that I mentioned above?

Comment: There are good examples/explanations in the link

Comment: @juharr, I don't have any exception. I just want to use date instead of text as I used above in my code.

Comment: @Alex K, where is that link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163361/how-can-i-add-user-supplied-input-to-an-sql-statement

Comment: In this link. I am not getting any information about to conversion or paramertized insert.

Comment: Look at the answer(s) *Use parameterized SQL* **Examples**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105913/discussion-between-nabia-saroosh-and-alex-k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTime.TryParseExact() is probably a better option but you could use regular expressions to ensure that the text entered is in the correct format to begin with.  You can display the format that you desire in a placeholder ("***Format must be yyyy-MM-dd***") on your form. To be saved in SQL Server the string could look like this "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"