# access[EN version] automatically converts date dd/MM/yyyy in MM/dd/yyyy

Tags: date, datetime, ms-access

I have this problem :

i have a small management program witch c# and DB Access 2016. 
My keyboard and my system language is in Italian . 
My DB Access is in English

In query I send a ***System.DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")*** date format that is for example

```
string update = "UPDATE RICHIESTA_IT SET RICHIESTA_IT.stato_approvazione = YES, RICHIESTA_IT.data_approvazione = #" + System.DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "# WHERE(((RICHIESTA_IT.ID_RichiestaIT) = " + iD_Richiesta + "))";
MessageBox.Show(update);
//qa is my object that help me to connection,query,disconnet to DB ..
qa.runNonQuery(update);

// without parametric query
// #06/04/2016#
```

but in access db I see

```
04/06/2016
```

This is a big problem when i read this date.

How to resolve it ?

I tried to set a mask .. but I have failed to resolve...

Comment: Are you trying to embed that string as a date literal in an INSERT or UPDATE statement?

Comment: No, because I think that i have an exception when I use INSERT statement. Type-safe different

Comment: What is the date format in the regional settings on your computer? By default Access should use that.

Comment: In control panel i have setting italian language ad keyboard. What and where is regional setting?!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the segment of your code where you are attempting to use this `System.DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` value.

Comment: edit done. I m sure that i send a correct date format ("dd/MM/yyyy") because I show in msgbox ... @GordThompson thanks for your trust :D :D .. I joke :)

Comment: Control Panel > Region and Language - check the "Date and time formats" on the "Formats" tab. You will probably find that these are set wrong, so update them then close and restart MS Access.

Comment: @DavyC thanks, date format was setting good ;) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using parameters.

You tried to guess the format internally used by MS Access and failed. **If** you use `#...#` date literals, they **must** use the `yyyy-MM-dd` or the `MM/dd/yyyy` format (I'd prefer the former, since it's unabiguous). This is how `#...#` date literals are defined. You **cannot** use a localized (e.g. Italian) format here.

To solve your immediate problem, you can use

```
... #" + System.DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "# ...
```

or

```
... #" + System.DateTime.Today.ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy") + "# ...
```

But please, consider [using parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35163361/87698). It's not hard and you avoid **all** those ugly date format/decimal point/string escaping problems.

Comment: Working good! Thanks! 

Why running good despite you set first _MM_ and after _dd_ ?? 
Infact with `(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy")` running good meantime `(@"dd\/MM\/yyyy")` set before month and after day .. Why ?
PS: i know parametrized queries thanks. ;)

Comment: @Heinzi: The _yyyy-mm-dd format_ is understood by any version of Access, not only "recent" versions.

Comment: @rul3z: In cases like this, _always_ use the _yyyy-mm-dd_ (or mm-dd-yyyy) sequence as the _dd-mm-yyyy_ sequence will fail when _dd_ can be read as a month.

Comment: @Gustav Thanks.. But i ask why `(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy")` working good and why `(@"dd\/MM\/yyyy") ` not . 

I want write in db `27/04/2016` and not `04/27/2016` but if use `(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy")` access set `27/04/2016`
meantime `(@"dd\/MM\/yyyy") ` access set `04/27/2016` .. It reversed!
my ask is why .. Nothing what.. 

if I understand why I 'm not mistaken the most , if I ask as 'how' I don't learn  :)

Comment: You must distinguish between the date _value_ and the date _format_. The value is used in the code. To _display_ it for the user, you apply a format, typically that of your system settings. To _concatenate_ it into an SQL string, you must format the value as a string expression understood by SQL. This format is typically yyyy-mm-dd and never dd-mm-yyyy. To avoid this trouble, use parameters as already noted.

Comment: @Gustav: I changed my answer. I *seem* to remember that this feature was not available in the very early versions (which required the VBA literal syntax #MM/dd/yyyy#), but I might be mistaken. Anyway, it works with Access 2000 (just tested it) and anything before that should be "old enough" not to matter (in addition, I don't have an older version available to prove my point).