# Database access troubles

Tags: c#, database

I am trying to display the list of **cars** that are provided by the **dealer** **Toyota** in a Gridview

I get the information from a database called **Dealership.accdb**
The name of the table is **Table1**
The table has two columns **dealer** and **car**

But I keep getting this error
"Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters."

The code works fine when I use it to display the list of **"dealers"**
But when I try to display the list of cars provided by the dealer it shows the error I mentioned above

```
          using System;
          using System.Collections.Generic;
          using System.Linq;
          using System.Web;
          using System.Web.UI;
          using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
          using System.Data;
          using System.Data.OleDb;

          public partial class toyota : System.Web.UI.Page
          {
             protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
             {
                 OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();

                 connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                 Data Source=C:\Users\Student\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\WebSite1\Dealership.accdb";
                 connect.Open();

                 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Car FROM Table1 WHERE dealer = Toyota", connect);

                 OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

                 DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                 adapter.Fill(dt);

                 GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                 GridView1.DataBind();
             }
         }
```

Comment: it thinks Toyota is a field, not a string. You need to put quotes round it

Comment: Note: Quoting might fix your immediate problem, but should you ever replace the hard-coded "Toyota" value with a user-supplied value, [you need to use parameterized SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35163361/87698).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should properly quote your variables:

```
SELECT Car FROM Table1 WHERE dealer = 'Toyota'
```

Instead of:

```
SELECT Car FROM Table1 WHERE dealer = Toyota
```

Now it is trying to match the field `dealer` with the field named `Toyota`, where I think you meant to check for the *value* Toyota.

You could parameterize your query too, so you can easily get *BMW* next time:

```
SELECT Car FROM Table1 WHERE dealer = ?
```

And in your C#:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Car FROM Table1 WHERE dealer = ?", connect);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", "Toyota");
```

Comment: @Destiny - Consider marking the answer as expected and/or upvoting it, if it worked for you.