# How to add a value to Sql CommandText

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Nowadays I am programming a cricket scoring software and all the details are saved in a database. I want to know how to add +1 to the field "**W**" in the database when click "**Wicket**".

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE database.table SET W=W+1 WHERE bowler='" & frmmain.lblbowler.Text & "' "
```

In this code `frmmain.lblbowler.text` contains the bowler name.

Is this code correct? What changes must do? Please be kind enough to answer.

Comment: The code looks correct. Did you get an error?

Comment: We don't know the structure of your database but I think it is correct. What is your question again? Just check the query or advice about connecting to SQL database?

Comment: It's not appropriate to come here and ask us if your code is correct.  You need to run the code and if it works then you know it's correct and only if it doesn't do you post a question here and provide us with all the relevant information, e.g. error messages.

Comment: Also, you should learn how to use parameters in your ADO.NET code.  Steve O'Keefe dismissed Angelo Mathews not long ago in the current Aust/SL Test and your app would crash if it was scoring that game.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Can I add parameters instead of frmmain.lblbowler.text

Comment: No you can't, and some research on the subject would reveal that that's a nonsensical question. Check out my blog post on the subject.  http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35163361/87698

Answer (score 1):

Don’t ever build a query this way! The input `frmmain.lblbowler.Text` is typically retrieved from a TextBox control on either a Windows form or a Web Page. Anything placed into that TextBox control will be put into `frmmain.lblbowler.Text` and added to your SQL string. This situation invites a hacker to replace that string with something malicious. In the worst case, you could give full control of your computer away.

Instead of dynamically building a string, as shown in your code, use parameters.

Anything placed into a parameter will be treated as field data, not part of the SQL statement, which makes your application much more secure.

Try the following

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE database.table SET W=W+1 WHERE bowler = @bowler"

command.Parameters.Add("@bowler", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
command.Parameters("@bowler").Value =  frmmain.lblbowler.Text
```