# how to remove System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException error?

Tags: asp.net

When I am performing update operation then the error

> "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code"

occured,how can I remove this?this error is occured on cmd.ExecuteNonQuery (line below the insert query)

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection() ;
        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=ADMIN\LOCALHOST;Initial Catalog=maha;Integrated Security=True;";

                con.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into [dbo].[student]([ID],[NAME],[DOB],[GENDER]) Values ('" + TB1.Text + "','" + TB2.Text + "','" + TB3.Text + "','" + @rm + "')", con);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
}
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=ADMIN\LOCALHOST;Initial Catalog=maha;Integrated Security=True;";
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update [dbo].[student] set [ID]='" + TB1.Text + "',[NAME]='" + TB2.Text + "',[DOB]='" + TB3.Text + "',[GENDER]='" + @rm + "' where [ID]=='" + TB1.Text + "'", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
 }
```

Comment: You code is open for SQL Injection attack. I would recommend you to start using [SqlParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The exception may indicate that there is some error in the SQL you are creating. What is the `CommandText` of `cmd` after you created the command?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/35163361/87698. As a side effect, it might also fix your original problem. About your original problem: Your exception also has an *exception message*. Look for it and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have some errors in your code and you can catch that `Exception` by using `try{} catch{}`.Besides I would suggest to use `using` statement.

**ERROR**

In both of the `Insert` query you are using an `SqlParameter` i.e `@r` and you are not providing value for it. So it will obviously throw and `Exception`,
`==` in the `Update` query also is an error, It doesn't exist in SqlServer.

Now try this code:

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    try{
        string constr = @"Data Source=ADMIN\LOCALHOST;Initial Catalog=maha;"+
                     "Integrated Security=True;";
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr)){        
            if(con.State==ConnectionState.Closed){
                con.Open();
            }
            string query= "Update [dbo].[student] set [ID]=@id,[NAME]=@name, [DOB]=@dob,"+
                      "[GENDER]=@rm Where [ID]=@id";
            using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con)){
                cmd.CommandType=CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",TB1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",TB2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob",TB3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rm",rmvalue); //i don't know it's value
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
                //success message here      
            }
        }  
    }catch(Exception ex){
          //print your error message here e.g errLabel.Text=ex.Message;
    }
```

}

I suggest you use this approach for both `Insert` and `Update`

Comment: i tried this code,but it does not execute the query.always comes to catch block. how to solve this?

Comment: And what does the Exception Message say?

Comment: Message which i print in catch block, how can i solve this? I want to execute the query without any exception

Comment: Let me know the exact error you see. When the exception is thrown, a small `cross` icon must there next to `catch(Exception ex)` put you mouse on that icon you will be able to see the message. And my guess for the errror is your `connection string`, if the exception is thrown everytime you execute the code.

Comment: There was a small typo in the update query here `set [ID]='@id'`. it must be `set [ID]=@id`. changed now try again.

Comment: the exception is come because of this cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); line,Connection string is not an error?