# Exception: No value given for one or more required parameters in VB.NET & MS-ACCESS DB

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I work with an Inventory System. I have an error on my code, it says

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

and the error was thrown to `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`. What does it mean? can someone help me? By the way this code is for deducting Item Quantity on Database. Sorry for my bad English.

```vb
con.Open()
Dim sqlQry As String = "UPDATE [tbl_Stocks] 
                        SET [Quantity] = [Quantity] - @QU 
                        WHERE Products='" & lbPro.Text & "'"
Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQry, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QU", lbQuan.Text)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    MsgBox("Save Successfully!")
End Using
```

Comment: Use a parameter also for the Products value, then check if the fields names are written correctly

Comment: What is the datatype of the column Quantity?

Comment: Please [use parameterized SQL instead](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35163361/87698).

Comment: @Steve the data type of column Quantity is Number on the database

Comment: Are the column names and the table name written correctly?. Usually this error happens with ms-access when you mispell some name.

Comment: Oops, My bad I misspelled the column name product to products.

Comment: it's working right now! thanks to all of you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any flaw. Try this substitute(a little tweak sending both inputs via parameter)

```
con.Open()
Dim sqlQry As String = "UPDATE [tbl_Stocks] SET [Quantity] = [Quantity] - @QU " &
                       "WHERE Products=@prod"
Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQry, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QU", lbQuan.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prod", lbPro.Text)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    MsgBox("Save Successfully!")
End Using
```

Comment: i try to use this code but the error "No value given for one or more required parameters." still prompting.

Comment: have you noticed the `@prod`?. If not then make sure values of `lbQuan` & `lbPro` are not empty or null

Comment: the only problem is I misspelled the column name product to products but the code is working! Thank you!