# how to make combobox to take data by selection and custom also both

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to insert data to my access database by combobox that have some item in it but some time when I want insert some thing there is not exist in my combobox how can write it down manually on my combobox and insert it to my db

[image]

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "insert into [data] ( [Description] ) values ('" + comboBox10Text + "' )";
cmd.Connection = con;
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted Successfully");
```

Comment: So what is the problem you should probably use comboBox10Text.Text and OleDbCommand.Parameters

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually almost there, just a dot missing. `comboBox10.Text` will give you the entered text:

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into [data] ( [Description] ) values ('" + comboBox10.Text + "' )";
```

I would suggest to check for emptiness and use parameterized sql commands to [avoid SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163361/how-can-i-add-user-supplied-input-to-an-sql-statement)

Comment: ah ok, if you don't mind empty values. Still, there is a dot missing in `comboBox10Text` and you really should consider to parameterize your query

Answer (score 0):

You can add another item to your combobox something like other. Then check the selected item, if it is other then enable a textbox and read the input value from it. Otherwise, read the input value from the combobox.

Comment: but I want to be in same combobox