# select query where clause with more than 1 value

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a column named `ast_code`

[image]

which I have already retrieved to a `string` variable. I'm trying to run a `select` query using a `where` clause based on the string value that I stored in that variable.

Here's the code I tried:

```
public void grid()
{
     datatable dt = new datatable();
     SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
     try
     {
     command.Connection = myConnection;
     command.CommandText = "SELECT code, name from table.menu where code <> '"+ ast_code + "'";
     adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            myConnection.Open();
     }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error" + ex);
        }
        myConnection.Close();
     gridControl1.DataSource = dt;          
    }
```

When I ran the query, it returned no results unless the value in the string variable only contained one value (e.g. `0110300`).

I then tried to transform the contents of the variable:

```
 ast_code = a.Replace(';',',').Replace(' ','\'');
```

but it returned an error due a missing `'`. Don't mind the `a`; it was a parsing variable value. I have already tried to store them to a `list` but that isn't working properly, either.

What I need to do is generate a `where` clause that can handle multiple values.

**UPDATE**

iam using @rbr94 suggestion `ast_code = a.Replace("; ", "', '");`

```
 command.CommandText = "SELECT code, name from table.menu where code not in '"+ ast_code + "'";
```

it works when iam using the top `string value`, but for the second row `string value give me an error
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, I would advise you to use parameterized queries. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163361/how-can-i-add-user-supplied-input-to-an-sql-statement

Comment: @xszaboj if i use parameterized, only 1 value, and also need to put it manually via code..

Answer (score 2):

The error you get results from wrongly setting the `'` in your where clause. I give an example:

You have a string like this: `0110300; 0110370`

Then you use  `ast_code = a.Replace(';',',').Replace(' ','\'');` and this results in this: `0110300,'0110370`. When you use this in your where clause it is obvious that this won't work:

```
where code <> '0110300,'0110370'
```

First of all use `WHERE NOT IN` and then you need to do the following:

C#:

```
ast_code = string.Format("'{0}'", a.Replace("; ","', '"));
```

SQL:

```
 where code NOT IN (" + ast_code + ")

 //results in
 where code NOT IN ('0110300','0110370')
```

This sets `'` before and after your `ast_code` string. Then you replace your `;` and the space after it with `'; '` so that each value is encapsulated with `'` marks on both sides.

This will result in this: `'0110300', '0110370'`

Comment: thx for reply, but when itry to put `ast_code = string.Format('\'{0}\'', a.Replace('; ','\', \''));` its give me error of `too many characters in character literal`

Comment: `('; ')` isnt it two character including the space ?

Comment: @chopperfield I edited my post. I wrongly used `'` instead of `"` because it's a `string` instead of a `char`

Comment: i think maybe should using the `list<>` for seperated them into 1 slot (or kind like of an array) the thing is i dont know how to use it when iam putting it , in the `where clause`

Comment: @chopperfield You can do this. Upvote my answer if it is useful for you

Comment: @chopperfield And my propose you should do the same as your approach if you use `string.Format("'{0}'", a.Replace("; ","', '"))` and in SQL `where code NOT IN (" + ast_code + ")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128320/discussion-between-rbr94-and-chopperfield).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `NOT IN` in your statement like this:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT code, name from table.menu where code NOT IN ('" + ast_code.Replace(";", "','") + "')";
```

Comment: its still showing the 2nd value. e.g i got two value - 001,002  then the first value 001 was not showing (was true) but the second value 002 still showing..

Comment: That's because it must be `ast_code.Replace("; ", "', '")`

Answer (score 0):

so, my solution to my own problem is that first iam splitting it to store in a `list<>` 
so iam just directly store the `ast_code = a`

and then the code i use to store

```
  string[] code_asst = ast_code.Split(';');
  List<string> clean_code_asst = new List<string>();
  foreach (string s in code_asst)
        {
            clean_code_asst.Add("'"+s.Trim()+"'");
        }
  string types = string.Join(",", clean_code_asst.ToArray());
```

for the query i use is

```
  var sql = "Select code from table.menu where code NOT IN ("+types+")";
  command.CommandText = sql;
```