# It says ambigious column name CarId

Tags: c#

```
string carid = Request.QueryString["carde"];
            var conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CONSTRING"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT cars.*, img.img FROM cars INNER JOIN img ON cars.carid = img.carid where cars.carid= "+carid+"", con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda1.Fill(dt);
            cardetail.DataSource = dt;
            cardetail.DataBind();
```

I cant find anything wrong with this query. 
Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use an `SqlParameter` with your command, you have an SQL Injection vulnerability.

Comment: Dont know how to do it.

Comment: Great time to learn!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163361/how-can-i-add-user-supplied-input-to-an-sql-statement

Comment: You may think to dig into the exception details. Maybe you can post it too.

Answer (score 0):

You inner join has a table with another carid column name.

Please include table schemas if you want a more solid assessment.

Comment: He's defining the columns by table names in the on-part. Cant be ambigious. Either this isnt the current code or the wildcard `*` in the select is raising it (dont think so).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the ambigous `carid` but you should use the parameters as below. Try this, and we'll see the rest.

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(
    "SELECT cars.*, img.img" +
    "FROM cars, img" +
    "WHERE cars.carid = img.carid AND cars.carid = @carid", con);

cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carid", carid);
```

Comment: `cars.* selectedCars` are you serious? How can multiple columns have a single name? Syntax error?

Comment: I am guessing the ambiguity is caused by that :) Hence the OP should do something about the selected names. But it's been a while I wasn't dealing with sql queries! :) admitted. I'll fix it in a min.

Comment: Think so too thats the only possibility. But you cant give a synonym for multiple selections. He would have to define each selection by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your wildcard `*` has to be the problem in here.

```
SELECT cars.*, img.img FROM cars INNER JOIN...
```

Instead of selecting everything from `cars` by wildcard, select them manually (which is better either way when coding). Using `SELECT *` when coding is a bad practice!

```
SELECT cars.col1, cars.col2, cars.carid, cars.., img.img FROM cars INNER JOIN...
```

---

**EDIT:**

This is for sure the only possibility I can think of. However you havnt provided which database-system you are using. I just tried that on mssql and **couldnt** reproduce it.

*Was too lazy to create tables for testing, so I went with some pseudo-tables*

```
SELECT a.*, b.a FROM (SELECT 1 a, 2 b, 3 ab UNION SELECT 2, 2, 2) a
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 1 a, 2 b, 3ab UNION SELECT 2, 2, 2) b
ON a.a = b.a
```

No error raised even with `a.*` where `a` and `b` have the same columns.

Comment: Thinking on the issue for a third time, the only case we can be correct on our guess is that the `cars` table has multiple columns with the same name. Is this even possible?

Comment: No its not. `cars.*` means `everything from the cars table`. It depends on how the database translates this. If it gets translated to `SELECT col1, col2, carid, img.img` the error raises because `carid` is presented in both tables.

`cars.carId` and `cars.*` are very different things.

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen Check my edit. Reproducing not possible for me. He probably uses a strange database that cant handle this case.