# Unable to insert into table whilst using square brackets

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, syntax-error

The problem is the strings I am inserting into the database have spaces within them but when I try to use the square bracket around the string to avoid `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression` error it gives me the error:

> No value given for one or more required parameters

```
TblCustomer.CommandTable("INSERT INTO TblCustomer ([CustomerCode],[FirstName]," + 
    "[SecondName],[Topics],[Countries]) Values(['" +
    TblCustomer.StrGenerateRandomCode("TblCustomer",15) + "'],['" + FirstName + "'],['" +
    SecondName+"'],['" + Topic + "'],['" + Country + "]');");
```

Here is the query and everything is spelled correctly because I am able to insert into the table without the square brackets and no spaces within the string I am inserting.

Comment: MySQL does not recognize square braces.  Use backticks, if you need to escape the values which you do not.

Comment: the values should never be in square brackets. if at all, then only the column *names*. tags are not clear: ms-access, sql, t-sql?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention but it is not MySQL but Microsoft SQL.

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting issues.  And yes, don't put brackets around your values.

Comment: Data does not get wrapped in square brackets in MS SQL. Only the columns. Remove the brackets from your VALUES.

Comment: When i remove the square brackets i get the error "'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ''Ses'Ghan','Ronn'Gun Steelarm''.'"

Comment: single quote is a string delimeter. you need to double up single quotes

Comment: Forget all that handling with quotes -> **use parameters** or you will be hit by little bobby tables => https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Could you show me a quick example of how you would use parameters instead of the quotes, please?

Comment: See [How can I add user-supplied input to an SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35163361/719186)

Comment: [Bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp) to the rescue

Comment: btw. there is no column name which would require brackets. no spaces, no reserved word.

Comment: @JacobH You should avoid AddWithValue it causes trouble sometimes.

Comment: What should I use instead of the AddWithValue?

Comment: You should be able to use `AddWithValues` just fine with the values you are using- the only possible exception would be the `StrGenerateRandomCode` depending on what that is doing. If you do have problems, you can just use create [SqlParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) and add that to the command