# ms-Access is removing leading zeros from a string

Tags: ms-access, vb6

In the below code, the value of `skuSet.Fields(0)`, which is a text field in the database, is "000000002".

```
If skuSet.RecordCount = 0 Then
   sql = "SELECT Stock_Code FROM Stock WHERE Stock_Code = '" & stkLine.StockCode & "'"
   Set skuSet = dbStock.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset)
End If

sql = "SELECT * FROM PickedByPicco WHERE OrderID = " & stkLine.OrderId & " AND StockCode = '" & skuSet.Fields(0) & "'"
Set SOPSLineSet = dbSOPS.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset)

If SOPSLineSet.RecordCount = 0 Then
    sql = "INSERT INTO PickedByPicco(OrderID, StockCode, Qty, ScannedBy, ProcessedBy, processed) VALUES(" & stkLine.OrderId & _
          ", " & skuSet.Fields(0) & ", " & stkLine.Quantity & ", '" & stkLine.UserId & "', '', False)"

dbSOPS.Execute (sql)
```

When I step through the code, the value in `skuSet.Fields(0)` is still the same, as expected.

When the query has been executed, I check the `PickedByPicco` table, and the `StockCode` field shows just a value of 2 instead, and it's removed all of the leading 0's.

Why would it be doing this and how can I stop it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because your INSERT statement looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO PickedByPicco (...) VALUES (..., 000000002, ...)
```

when it should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO PickedByPicco (...) VALUES (..., '000000002', ...)
```

(Note the quotes around your value.)

---

Normally, I'd tell you to use parameterized SQL, because [SQL creation by string concatenation is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35163361/87698), but, unfortunately, DAO's `Database.Execute` does not support that. So, the next best thing is to properly escape strings. To do that:

- put single quotes around your value and
- escape any single quotes occurring in your value:

I.e. this line

```
", " & skuSet.Fields(0) & ", " & ...
```

becomes

```
", '" & Replace(skuSet.Fields(0), "'", "''") & "', " & ...
```

While you are at it, be sure to replace single quotes in your other strings as well! Currently, a UserId of `O'Brien` would break your SQL, and [other values might do worse](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: I was hoping for the relevant XKCD, and I was not disappointed.

Comment: Wow, thank you, I'd never known how to get around using single quotes in SQL statements using DAO but I'll certainly be using them now, thanks again!