# Query with Date and Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2014

In my database, using `SQL Server 2014`, with a table named `TableOberge` and with column named `Date-In` of type `Date`, and with a second column named `Hour-In` of type `Time(7)`.
With this query I want to display the records that have reached their dates and times in DatagridView1... but I have failed to display them correctly.

Any Help please:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dbb_Connection()
    Using InfoAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TABLEOBERGE WHERE [DATE_IN] >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) AND [HOUR_IN] >= convert(time(0),getDate())", StrCon)
        InfoTable = New DataTable
        InfoAdapter.Fill(InfoTable)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = InfoTable
    End Using
End Sub
```

My code for add record :

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dbb_Connection()
    Using Command As New SqlCommand With {.Connection = StrCon}
        With Command.Parameters
            Command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [TABLEOBERGE] ([ID], [FIRSTNAME], [PHONE], [ADRESSE], [DATE_OUT], [HOUR_OUT], [DATE_IN], [HOUR_IN]) VALUES (@ID, @FIRSTNAME, @PHONE, @ADRESSE, @DATE_OUT, @HOUR_OUT, @DATE_IN, @HOUR_IN)"
            .AddWithValue("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox1.Text
            .AddWithValue("@FIRSTNAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
            .AddWithValue("@PHONE", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text
            .AddWithValue("@ADRESSE", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text
            .AddWithValue("@DATE_OUT", SqlDbType.Date).Value = TextBox5.Text
            .AddWithValue("@HOUR_OUT", SqlDbType.Time).Value = TextBox6.Text
            .AddWithValue("@DATE_IN", SqlDbType.Date).Value = TextBox7.Text
            .AddWithValue("@HOUR_IN", SqlDbType.Time).Value = TextBox8.Text
        End With
        If StrCon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then StrCon.Open()
        If Command.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
            MsgBox("SUCCED ADD", MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxRtlReading, "SUCCES")
        Else
            MsgBox("ERROR FATAL", MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxRtlReading, "ERROR")
        End If
        StrCon.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?862331-Display-record-with-condition-of-date-and-time
And Here 
https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1851524/dotnet/langages/vb-net/afficher-records-conditions-date-time/

Comment: Hi there, I have added some relevant tags so your post has more visibility. Have you tried running your query in SSMS to confirm the returned results are what you expect?

Comment: `but I have failed to display them correctly.` <= That is very ambiguous. Please elaborate exactly how it fails and include all the relevant details.

Comment: On a side note. IMO your design would be better if you used a single field for your date and time instead of splitting them into 2. `DateIn` of type `DateTime2(7)` would be a good fit. There are plenty of SQL functions that allow you to filter based strictly on time or date if this is necessary. It makes writing a query like above simpler.

Comment: With my failed query nothing happens and appears in Datagriview1.If i change query only like this ( SELECT * From TableOberge , StrCon) all records in my Table appear in my DataGridView1

Comment: How will the request be with (DateTime2 (7)) please

Comment: What you really need to post is the table structure, sample data and desired output. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/  I don't think this query is doing what you think it does, and I certainly don't think it is what you want it to do.

Comment: Thanks for the link .. what I want to do is fine here in link of my first post

Comment: "How will the request be with `DateTime2(7)`" <= `SELECT * FROM TABLEOBERGE WHERE [DATE_IN] <= GETDATE()`

Comment: I think you might have the equality comparer turned the wrong way. If you are looking for an expired date (ie. in the past) then that date should be **less than** the current date.

Comment: Maybe Igor is right? Your query mean: 1) [DATE_IN] >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) --> Every row with date greater or equal to TODAY  AND time (hh:mm:ss) greater than current time. That query means that if DATE_IN is tomorrow but the time is lower than current time the row won't be selected. Is your goal?

Comment: Well good luck then. If you would just post the details this would be a simple solution. Hope you get it figured out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have the equality comparer turned the wrong way. If you are looking for an expired date (ie. in the past) then that date should be **less than** the current date.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLEOBERGE 
WHERE [DATE_IN] <= CAST(getdate() as Date) AND [HOUR_IN] <= CAST(getDate() AS TIME)
```

---

IMO your design would be better if you used a single field for your date and time instead of splitting them into 2. `DateIn` of type `DateTime2(7)` would be a good fit. There are plenty of SQL functions that allow you to filter based strictly on time or date if this is necessary. It makes writing a query like above simpler.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEOBERGE WHERE [DATE_IN] <= GETDATE()
```

Comment: Thank you very much I started to learn your super lesson. I only have one problem left. How will the sqldatatypes be in this code for add record .. in my first update post

Comment: @ABIDINE - See [How can I add user-supplied input to an SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35163361/1260204).

Comment: @ABIDINE - also changing the question is frowned upon. If you have a new question you should post it as a new question instead of adding it to the existing one at a later point in time.

Comment: @ABIDINE - If the above has answered your original question please consider marking an answer using the checkmark on the left side of the answer.

Comment: Thanks dear Igor .. no i just want to know how will this datatype have a relationship with your query ..(      .AddWithValue("@DATE_IN", SqlDbType.Date).Value = TextBox7.Text
                .AddWithValue("@HOUR_IN", SqlDbType.Time).Value = TextBox8.Text)

Comment: @ABIDINE - you have to set the parameter's value using the the native .net type, not the string equivalent. Example: `.Value = DateTime.Now`. If all you have is text then you have to parse that first into a DateTime instance.

Comment: @ABIDINE - but again, this is a very different question than the one you started with originally. Please create a new question for further help. See also the link I posted earlier in the comment chain of this answer.

Comment: Thank you Igor .how to add reputation for your answer please ??

Comment: @ABIDINE - You can click on the checkmark on the left of the answer which turns it green. This is also called marking an answer.