# How to fix "Invalid Column Name" SQL Exception on MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, ado.net

I am trying to pass both Column name and the Value to be checked in the code at runtime. However I am getting an:

> "Invalid Column Name "

Exception. The code is as follows :

```
cmd = new SqlCommand();
con.Open();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO rezervasyon (Ad,Soyad,TelefonNo,OdaSayisi,KişiSayisi," +
                          "Ucret,Acıklama,GirisTarihi,CikisTarihi,KayitTarihi) VALUES " +
                          "(" + isim + ",'" + soyisim + "','" + telefon + "'," +
                          "'" + oda_sayisi + "','" + kisi_sayisi + "','" + ucret + "'," +
                          "'" + aciklama + "','" + giris_tar + "','" + cikis_tar + "'," +
                          "'" + current_tarih + "')";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
con.Close();
```

Comment: Pass your values using parameters, see [How can I add user-supplied input to an SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35163361/1260204)

Comment: Or use String.Format() to make it look more concise.

Comment: @PepitoSh or use interpolated string `$""`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've missed a single quote here `" + isim + "` and it should be `'" + isim + "'`. However you should always use [parameterized queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and also to get rid of this kind of errors.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO rezervasyon (Ad,Soyad,TelefonNo,OdaSayisi,KişiSayisi,Ucret" +
                  ",Acıklama,GirisTarihi,CikisTarihi,KayitTarihi) " +
                  "VALUES (@isim, @soyisim , ...)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isim", isim);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@soyisim", soyisim);
//Other parameters
```

Although specify the type directly and use the `Value` property is more better than `AddWithValue`:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@isim", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = isim;
```

[Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)