# why statement else not working / execute? c#

Tags: c#

i have a problem with my code c# where statements  **

```
if (i >0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("data ada");
}
```

** is not working..
maybe anyone in here can help me please :)

```
        if (pk_nama.Text == "" || pk_umur.Text == "" || pk_jenkel.Text == "" || pk_level.Text == "" || pk_alamat.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Isi data dulu");
        }
        else
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = konek.sambungkan();
            conn.Open();
            String query = "select * from tb_pekerja where pk_nama =' " + pk_nama.Text + " '";
            MySqlCommand cmde=new MySqlCommand(query, conn);

            dt = new DataTable();
            da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            da.Fill(dt);
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
            if (i >0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("data ada");
            }
            else
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id_pekerja.Text))
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Please clarify your question.

Comment: Did you debug the code? Checked the values of textboxes? What values you are entering in textboxes?

Comment: This is quite ambiguous , Please be specific which part of the code is not working

Comment: Side note: Showing example of [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163361/how-can-i-add-user-supplied-input-to-an-sql-statement) in what supposed to be [MCVE] is bad idea as it may invite downvotes and generally lead to unrelated discussions.

Comment: Can you be more specific?What is not working?

Comment: Tamas has the answer below, and people have highlighted the SQL injection vulnerability, but also note that `MySqlConnection`, `MySqlCommand` and `MySqlDataAdapter` are all `IDisposable` so should each be in a `using` block. And `int i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());` takes a perfectly good int, turns it into a string before converting it back again. In the code shown above, `cmde` is unused.

Comment: Whether the control enters in else block or not?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with this line. Besides the obvious injection vulnerability, it adds spaces to the PK, so you will never get any results.

```
string query = "select * from tb_pekerja where pk_nama =' " + pk_nama.Text + " '";
```

should be

```
// Warning still vulnerable to injections
string query = "select * from tb_pekerja where pk_nama ='" + pk_nama.Text + "'";
```

Using a prepared statement would solve the injection problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this will help you but there you go.

```
MySqlConnection conn = konek.connect();
conn.Open();
string query = "select * from tb_pekerja where pk_nama =' " + pk_nama.Text + " '";

dt = new DataTable();
da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
da.Fill(dt, "Pekerja"); // give the table a name

int i = dt.Tables["Pekerja"].Rows.Count;

if (i > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("data ada");
} else {
    // your code here...
}
```

Also listen to @Alexei Levenkov: do not construct SQL queries the way you do or you'll be vulnerable to SQL injection. Look into MySQL parameters.