# How to convert values of a datatable from string to integer

Tags: sql, .net

I'm making a fine calculator in a library system. In it,I need to calculate the fine of a given day. For this,I use a data table to load the fine amounts and then,I need to calculate the total fine amount by adding each fine amount.But I'm having a problem in parsing the fine values which are in string format to integer.Here is a screenshot of the error.

[Here is a screenshot of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGAWB.jpg)

And here is the code which I used to convert the string values to integer and calculate the total fine.

```
int sum1 = 0;
int myNum;       
String Display;

private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (rbtnToday.Checked == true)
        {
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
            Con.Open();
            String select_today_query = "SELECT Fine FROM BookReceiveMem WHERE RecDate='" + today + "'";
            Sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(select_today_query, Con);
            DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
            Sqlda.Fill(Dt);
            Con.Close();
            foreach (DataRow row in Dt.Rows)
            {
                myNum = int.Parse(Dt.Columns[0].ToString());
                sum1 = sum1 + myNum;
            }
            Display = sum1.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("Today Fine Amount is= " + Display, "Today Fine Calculation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
}
```

Is there any method to solve this problem?

Comment: Please do not create SQL queries by joining strings together. You should always use parametrised queries, otherwise you have a significant security risk from SQL injection.

Comment: So what should I do?Can you send me a sample code?

Comment: @KalinduPrabash you are asking about links to ADO.NET docs and tutorials. In fact, it's *this code* that's converting the value to a string, then trying to parse it. There are dozens if not hundreds of duplicate questions about this - don't do it. Don't call `.ToString()` on that field.

Comment: In your table `BookReceiveMem` what is the datatype for field `Fine`?

Comment: @KalinduPrabash what are you trying to do in the first place? If you only want to retrieve a sum, you don't need to use DataTable or `SqlDataAdapter` at all. Use `SELECT SUM(Fine) ...` with a SqlCommand and use ExecuteScalar to retrieve the result

Comment: @KalinduPrabash I suspect this is a course assignment. If you submit an answer using Datatable like this you'll fail. Even if you manage to get the correct *value* by accident, a good instructor would still fail you. You were asked to get a sum from the database using ADO.NET. To show you understand how SQL works, you'll use a `SUM()`, not try to load the data into a DataTable. For 100 values, `SUM()` will be 100+ times faster. You'd be expected to know the difference between the various ADO.NET classes as well. The class that executes commands is `SqlCommand`.

Comment: Always use parameterized sql and avoid string concatenation to add values to sql statements. See [How can I add user-supplied input to an SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35163361/1260204)

Answer (score 3):

Databases are *really* good at calculating things like a sum. If `Fine` is an integer in your database you can get it to sum all the rows and just return that:

```
SELECT SUM(Fine) As TotalFine 
FROM BookReceiveMem
WHERE RecDate = @recDate
```

Which you could call from code without ever needing a DataTable as follows:

```
using(var cmd = Con.CreatCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(Fine) As TotalFine FROM BookReceiveMem WHERE RecDate = @recDate";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@recDate",DateTime.Today);
    var result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    MessageBox.Show("Today Fine Amount is= " + result, "Today Fine Calculation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

}
```

Note that the above uses a [Parameterized Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712037/what-is-parameterized-query) which is [much safer](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet) than using string concatenation

---

However, a more direct answer to your question:

```
myNum = int.Parse(Dt.Columns[0].ToString());
```

Here you're getting the *Column* and trying to turn that to an integer. What you actually meant to do was get the `row` value (and you dont need to `Parse` it - it's already an integer!)

```
myNum = (int)row["Fine"];
```