# SqlBulkCopy Keeps failing at 1129500 records

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I am having a loss. I have a table with 5 years of data each year has about 4 million records so the table in total has 20 million records. I wrote this C# app that will select the year and then quarter and move that data to the Archive table. I tried playing with the BatchSize and BulkCopyTimeout but it always timeouts at `1129500 or 2093,000` records.

> Is there a better way to do this or something that I am missing in the
>   code?

```
Copied 1129500 so far...
Exception = Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

```
    public static bool SqlBulkCopy()
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("EcommerceConnectionString");
        string BKConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("BKConnectionString");

        // Open a sourceConnection to the AdventureWorks database.
        using (SqlConnection sourceConnection = new SqlConnection(BKConnectionString))
        {
            sourceConnection.Open();

            // Perform an initial count on the destination table.
            string queryString = "SELECT * from GuidelineLog";
            string queryClause = string.Format("where DATEPART(YEAR,LogDate) = '{0}' and DATEPART(QUARTER,LogDate) = '{1}'", 2015, 3);
            string TSQL = string.Format("{0} {1}", queryString, queryClause);
            SqlCommand commandRowCount = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + "dbo.GuidelineLogArchive", sourceConnection);
            commandRowCount.CommandTimeout = 900;
            long countStart = System.Convert.ToInt32(
            commandRowCount.ExecuteScalar());

            Console.WriteLine("Starting row count = {0}", countStart);
            WriteLog("Log_10_11_18.txt", String.Format("Starting row count = {0}", countStart));
            // Get data from the source table as a SqlDataReader.
            Console.WriteLine("Source table = {0}", TSQL);
            SqlCommand commandSourceData = new SqlCommand(TSQL, sourceConnection);
            commandSourceData.CommandTimeout = 900;
            SqlDataReader reader = commandSourceData.ExecuteReader();

            // Create the SqlBulkCopy object using a connection string. 
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.GuidelineLogArchive";
                // How many Rows you want to insert at a time
                //bulkCopy.BatchSize = 100000;
                bulkCopy.BatchSize = 500;
                // Set the timeout.
                bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;

                // Set up the event handler to notify after 4500 rows.
                bulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied += new SqlRowsCopiedEventHandler(OnSqlRowsCopied);
                bulkCopy.NotifyAfter = 4500;

                //(                  2093,000 row(s) affected)
                //Always stopping at 2093,000
                try
                {
                    // Write from the source to the destination.
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    WriteLog("Log_10_11_18.txt", String.Format("Exception = {0}", ex.Message));
                    return false;
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Close the SqlDataReader. The SqlBulkCopy
                    // object is automatically closed at the end
                    // of the using block.
                    reader.Close();

                }
                return true;
            }

            // Perform a final count on the destination 
            // table to see how many rows were added.
            long countEnd = System.Convert.ToInt32(commandRowCount.ExecuteScalar());
            Console.WriteLine("Ending row count = {0}", countEnd);
            WriteLog("Log_10_11_18.txt", String.Format("Ending row count = {0}", countEnd));
            Console.WriteLine("{0} rows were added.", countEnd - countStart);
            WriteLog("Log_10_11_18.txt", String.Format("{0} rows were added.", countEnd - countStart));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are source/destination on the same server?  Have you tried simply performing an INSERT INTO dest SELECT ... FROM src WHERE ...

Comment: @AlexK. Yes source/destination are on the same server I can perform a simply insert

Comment: I am not sure if it would solve the time out but you should always use parameterized sql and avoid string concatenation to add values to sql statements. See [How can I add user-supplied input to an SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35163361/1260204), and [Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: how long does it take to timeout?  Have you tried upping the 'SqlDataReader reader' timeout?

Comment: its timing out in about one minute, I will try upping the reader next

Comment: Try doing a query in SQL Server Management Studio and verify the number of rows.  Yo may have a bad value in the database that is giving the exception.  You may want to look at the source code from msdn to see if it may give a clue : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopy.cs,75a6fc3244bf82c5

Comment: Hm... aren'T you missing the command timeout on `commandSourceData`?

Comment: @Tyron78 I updated the code to include a timeout for the reader now.

Comment: It's probably the timeout on the original query - 900 ms probably isn't enough to execute and transfer all the data.

Comment: @Jefferson and did this additional timer solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had to increase the timeout on the reader 900 MS isn't enough to execute and transfer

See this note for [SqlCommand.CommandTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> This property is the cumulative time-out (for all network packets that
>   are read during the invocation of a method) for all network reads
>   during command execution or processing of the results. **A time-out can
>   still occur after the first row is returned**, and does not include user
>   processing time, only network read time.