# Inserting Data in table that contains foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm making an application in c# so I wanted to insert data in a table that contains a foreign key from another table.

Like this suppose you have foreign key (category_id) from categories table in your article table then you can insert data using this way.

```
INSERT INTO articles( article_name, article_content, category_id, img, url ) 

VALUES( '"+textbox1+"','"+textbox2+"' , ( SELECT category_id FROM categories WHERE categories.category_id = '"+textbox5+"') ,"+textbox3+"' , '"+textbox4+"')
```

Will this work ?

Comment: I think your query is wrong your looing for category_id where category_id = textbox value, I think that needs to be categoryText or something else.  Yes it would work but you should not build SQL like that you should use paramaters like this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Why didnt you try?

Comment: Can you show me an example as I'm an begineer

Comment: Mr Zach I'm think it will work but since I'm a beginner so I wanted some advices

Answer (score 0):

You would do this.

```
INSERT INTO articles( article_name, article_content, category_id, img, url ) 
SELECT '"+textbox1+"', '"+textbox2+"', category_id, "+textbox3+"' , '"+textbox4+"'
FROM categories 
WHERE categories.category_id = '"+textbox5+"'
```

although I am not sure why you would have `categories.category_id = '"+textbox5+"'` and use `categories.category_id` in the output of the select. Why not just use the categoryId it seems you already have?

But the main problem I see here is that it seems you are not using parameters. If you are using ado.net (ie. SqlConnection, SqlCommand, etc) you should be passing in parameters and not creating a concatenated string. See [How can I add user-supplied input to an SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35163361/1260204)

Comment: Okay I'll try to implement parameters

Answer (score 0):

Never ever Concatenate strings to generate a query tattoo this thing on your body. 
Here is how your code and Queries should interact with SQL server.

```
    private int InsertRecord(string articleName, string articleContent, string cId, string img, string url)
    {
        int rA;
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(@"YOUR CONNECTION STRING GOES HERE"))
        {
            using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Articles (article_name, article_content, category_id, img, url) values (@aName, @aContent, (SELECT category_id FROM categories WHERE categories.category_id = @cId), @img, @url)", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aName", articleName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aContent", articleContent);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cId", cId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", img);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@url", url);

                con.Open();

                rA = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                con.Close();
            }
        }

        return rA;
    }
```

`ADO.NET` is highly vulnerable to `SQL Injections` if you go by the string concatenation for your query.
Another thing is to use `Stored Procedures` for sql again that will also based on Parameterizing the `SqlCommand`.

Comment: Jamshaid Kamran I'll try this & get back to you thank you for your help.