# Date stored in DataBase as NULL is returned as 01/01/1900 and not as DateTime.MinValue

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a logic that does the following:

```
string myData =  Convert.ToDateTime(Info.ClosedDate) == DateTime.MinValue ? String.Empty : "(" + Info.ClosedDate + ")";
```

It should return ClosedDate in parenthesis if it is not stored as NULL in the database. Otherwise it should return an empty string.

The value of `Convert.ToDateTime(Info.ClosedDate)` is `01/01/1900` and the value of `DateTime.MinValue` is `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`

So, the condition will never return `String.Empty`

Currently the field in the object is represent as :

```
public string ClosedDate
{
    get { return _ClosedDate; }
    set { _ClosedDate = value; }
}
```

What is the best solution?

Comment: SQL `DateTime` is not C# `DateTime`.  Sql `DateTime2` == c# `DateTime`.  SQL DateTime min is `01/01/1900`.  [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings).

Answer (score 4):

**Don't store or model `DateTime` types as `string`.**

This applies to the data store but also to your models in the code. If it can be nullable in the database than model it as `Nullable<DateTime>` (alternate notation `DateTime?`) in your code. Only convert it to a `string` at the last possible moment, usually in the presentation layer. If you do that there is no need to do any type conversion when reading/writing to the data store. You also avoid ambiguity on the value interpretation (*like what value is null or is it localized as "dd/MM/yyyy" or "MM/dd/yyyy"*).

```
private DateTime? _ClosedDate;
public DateTime? ClosedDate
{
    get { return _ClosedDate; }
    set { _ClosedDate = value; }
}
```

*side note: the above could also be modeled as an auto property but I did not do so because it is not clear how the field is used in the model*

If you are not sure how to pass a `DateTime` instance to an ADO.NET query as a parameter in it's native format please review this previous question/answer: [How can I add user-supplied input to an SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35163361/1260204)

Answer (score 1):

You can compare against `SqlDateTime.MinValue`

```
Convert.ToDateTime(Info.ClosedDate) == SqlDateTime.MinValue? String.Empty : "(" + Info.ClosedDate + ")";
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.minvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Although its best to use DateTime as type for dates, your code should like this:

```
public DateTime ClosedDate
{
    get; set;
}
```

You can also use auto properties like this or private set upto the requirements.

```
public DateTime ClosedDate 
{
   get;
   set
   {
     Date = DateTime.Now;
   }
}
```

For string, you can use `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact` instead of `Convert.ToDateTime`.

If value is null then `Parse` or `ParseExact` returns `ArgumentNullException` and same way if value contains some invalid date format then it returns `FormatException`.

```
var convertedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```