# Why SQL query returns '01/01/1900' instead of an empty string when Date field is NULL?

Tags: sql, date, null

I'm testing some SQL query for return value.

The table I'm selecting from has a value `NULL` in a  `CloseDate` field.
I have a logic that checks if it is `NULL`, return an empty string. However, it returns `01/01/1900`

```
declare @value varchar(50) = '2346677888'
    Set @Value=@Value +'%'

    select CONVERT(varchar,ISNULL(m.CloseDate,''),101) as CloseDate from( 
    SELECT m.EdsClosedDate AS CloseDate
    FROM [dbo].[tblMyTable] m                   
    WHERE MID like @value) m
```

What's wrong with the query?

Comment: I believe this is related to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/q/54835384/1260204. When querying data with c# code it is best to always leave your data in native format. Example: do not convert a sql date to a varchar and then send it to c#. Instead leave it as a sql date/time so that the c# code can better work with the values. Only the presentation layer (the part of the code that displays the value) should convert the value to a string.

Comment: Thank you, Igor. The web service was already developed with a property of string value. So, to minimize changes for now I will do a conversion on a database level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression:

```
select CONVERT(varchar, ISNULL(m.CloseDate, ''), 101) as CloseDate
```

is more clearly written as:

```
select CONVERT(varchar(255), COALESCE(m.CloseDate, 0), 101) as CloseDate
```

That is, the empty string is equivalent to a date value of "0".  SQL Server starts counting dates from 1900-01-01, which is why you see that in your results.

I'm not sure what you are expecting.  If you want an empty string, assign that *after* converting the value to a string:

```
select COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(255), m.CloseDate, 101), '') as CloseDate
```