# insert function is not taking the correct column names that were defined?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I have a registration page where the user can enter email into mail.Text and password into pass.Text, but when I click the enter button I get an error, it seems the sytem thinks the hashed password and the email address are column names so I get inavlid column names followed by the entered email and hashed password, I'm not sure what I've done wrong but I think it may be to do with my INSERT function.

```
private void enterdetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = String.Format("INSERT INTO tbl_register(email,password) VALUES({0},{1})",
        mail.Text,Hashing.ComputeHash(pass.Text, Supported_HA.SHA256,  
        ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Supported_HA.SHA256")));
    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(@"");
    sqlconn.Open();
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn);
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlconn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: SHA* is too fast for passwords; use bcrypt.

Comment: The reason of your error is simple and you could have avoided it if you had used the parameters

Comment: password as a column name is also a bad idea

Comment: Always use parameterized sql and avoid string concatenation to add values to sql statements. See [How can I add user-supplied input to an SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35163361/1260204), and [Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Also wrap your connection instances in `using` blocks (that goes for any instance where `IDisposable` is implemented by the type).

Comment: Also `password` and `email` are reserved words in some RDBMS's. You should escape them using brackets. `([email], [password])`

Comment: Thanks for the information I will look into what you guys have mentioned, this is just for a homework assignment but I did realise with research that there are more secure methods. Could you tell me where the error lies because I can't seem to fix it.

Comment: You aren't using parameters is the error.  You are passing text as numbers, essentially.

Answer (score 1):

- Always use parameterized sql and avoid string concatenation to add values to sql statements. See [How can I add user-supplied input to an SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35163361/1260204), and [Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/). This is the main problem in your code.
- Also wrap your connection instances in `using` blocks (that goes for any instance where `IDisposable` is implemented by the type).
- Also `password` and `email` are reserved words in some RDBMS's. You should escape them using brackets. `([email], [password])`

See your edited code, make sure you select the correct `SqlDbType` as well as length. I took some guesses on both.

```
private void enterdetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO tbl_register([email],[password]) VALUES(@email,@password)";

    using(SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(@""))
    using(SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn))
    {
        sqlconn.Open();
        comm.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = mail.Text
        comm.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 256).Value = Hashing.ComputeHash(pass.Text,  Supported_HA.SHA256, ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Supported_HA.SHA256"));

        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help it seems like  parameterized sql is very important so I will look into this. I have tried your suggestion and the old error has gone, I now get inavlid cast type can't convert string to binary. The datatypes for my db are both varbinary max so i changed email from varchar to varbinary but I am still getting the same casting error, would you have an idea as to why I would be facing this issue?

Comment: @craibson - `mail.Text` is a string and you want to insert into the column `email`. Seems to me your chose the wrong data type in your Db Schema, that should probably be varchar or nvarchar and not varbinary.

Comment: Yeah that was the issue my bad. Your help was really appreicated also the help of the other commentors. I already had a login page before I had the hashing function where the user could login and I had sql select function to check plain text pasword and email, now that I have hashing implemented will my login code be vastly different?

Comment: @craibson - No but instead of comparing the plain text passwords you will want to hash the password input in the login screen and compare that to the stored hash. Again, use parameters. If this is for an actual prod. site be sure to research hash algorithms as the SHA is not suitable for passwords. A better alternative would be any of these 3: [pbkdf2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2), [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt), [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)

Comment: @craibson - finally please consider marking an answer using the checkmark on the left side of the answer.