# Is it possible to do an INSERT INTO SELECT statement using data from more than 1 table?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

Question as above. The SQL code I am currently using is as follows:

```
"INSERT INTO [tblClasses/Students] (StudentID, ClassID) " & _
"SELECT StudentID FROM tblStudent WHERE Username = @StudentUser " & _
"SELECT ClassID FROM tblClasses WHERE ClassName = @ClassName ;"
```

When I try to run this query, I receive the following error message:

> 'Number of query values and destination fields are not the same'

Clearly, the method I am using does not work, so does anyone know the correct way of writing the query?

Comment: You want to insert in 1 table ? How do you know that StudentID is related to a specific ClassID ?

Comment: The code is to allow a teacher to add a student into a specific class, both of which have already been selected prior to the query being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a single SELECT .. FROM .. statement as source. Normally you'd use a JOIN, but if the tables aren't related, use a cartesian product.

```
INSERT INTO [tblClasses/Students] (StudentID, ClassID)
SELECT tblStudent.StudentID, tblClasses.ClassID 
FROM tblStudent, tblClasses 
WHERE tblStudent.Username = @StudentUser 
  AND tblClasses.ClassName = @ClassName
```

Not sure if this will create duplicate records. If necessary, use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

[How to use SQL parameters in VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163361/how-can-i-add-user-supplied-input-to-an-sql-statement/49499486#49499486)

---

To test the query in Access, use `[StudentUser]` and `[ClassName]` for the parameters and supply the values when asked for them.

For some reason, Access trips over `[ClassName]` unless explicitly specified as parameter. Use this:

```
PARAMETERS StudentUser Text ( 255 ), ClassName Text ( 255 );
INSERT INTO [tblClasses/Students] ( StudentID, ClassID )
SELECT tblStudent.StudentID, tblClasses.ClassID
FROM tblStudent, tblClasses
WHERE tblStudent.Username = [StudentUser] 
  AND tblClasses.ClassName = [ClassName];
```

Comment: I guess that depends on how you run the SQL statement and how you pass the parameters. To see if the query works in principle, run it in Access (use `[StudentUser]` and `[ClassName]` for the parameters and supply the values when asked for them).

Comment: This was air code, but I just verified that it works. Double-check all table and column names, make sure you have a comma in `FROM tblStudent, tblClasses`. @walnut39

Comment: Odd. Try switching the query from SQL view to Design view. If that doesn't throw an error, please make a screenshot and add a link to it.

Comment: Hm. This looks correct. It should ask you for both parameters and insert one record. I'm curious why not. If you want, zip and upload the database to e.g. http://www.tinyupload.com/ and post the link.

Comment: See the link in my answer.