# Trying to solve embedded SQL code syntax error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I have a fairly simple web app that is used to let people interact with a local database. The embedded SQL is throwing the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '<'.'

This only happens when the text box is empty. If it contains data everything works as it should. I would like for the query to essentially ignore the field if it is blank.

```
protected void findBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM[OEM_Ref] WHERE DrawID like CASE WHEN " + drawerIDbox.Text + " <> '' THEN '" + drawerIDbox.Text + "%' ELSE '%' End";

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(query , sqlCon);
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);

        GridView1.DataSource = dtbl;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add user-supplied input to an SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163361/how-can-i-add-user-supplied-input-to-an-sql-statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have the single quotes around the text in your WHEN statement.

```
WHEN '" + drawerIDbox.Text + "' <> '' THEN '"
```

On a side note, you should really not concatenate user input this way; research SQL Injection.

Comment: Nailed it! I do know about SQL Injection attacks but this will only be on our local intranet, and so I'm not as concerned about it as I would be if it was on the public internet. I may still write a procedure for it though, Thanks for the help!