# How to subtract in Ms Access using VB.Net?

Tags: database, vb.net

Hello every one i have 2 tables in ms access i just want to ask what is the code for subtracting the BALANCE-Amount Paid?

**(Table1)Loan_Information**

1. Date_Today
2. ID_No
3. FirstName
4. LastName
5. Loan_Amount
6. Interest
7. Due
8. Balance

**(Table2)Payment**

1. ID_No
2. FirstName
3. LastName
4. Amount Paid

Here's The Code that i tried. it only saving the paymentinfo but doesn`t subtract the Balance in (Table_1) Loan_Information

```
ds = New DataSet
adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("insert into [Payment] ([Date_Today], [ID_No], [FirstName], [LastName], [Amount_Paid]) VALUES " & "('" & txtPaymentDate.Text & "','" & txtPaymentIDNo.Text & "','" & txtPaymentFirstName.Text & "','" & txtPaymentLastName.Text & "','" & txtPaymentAmount.Text & "')", conn)
adapter.Fill(ds, "Payment")


ds2 = New DataSet
adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("update [Loan_Information] set Balance = Balance - '" & txtPaymentAmount.Text & "' where ID_No = " & txtIDNo.Text, conn)
adapter.Fill(ds2, "Loan_Information")
```

Comment: **Always use parameterized sql and avoid string concatenation** to add values to sql statements. See [How can I add user-supplied input to an SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35163361/1260204), and [Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Remember that for access (ole) you need to use `?` as place holders and parameters are position dependent (array position must match location in the statement). Use parameters and your "issue" will go away.

Comment: Okay, Thank you so much i'll try the reference that you given.

Comment: @Igor You can use named parameters on the `VALUES()` side, too. Only the position matters.

Comment: @Igor Your link uses `.AddWithValue` I believe the `.Add` method with datatype and size is preferred.

Comment: @Igor Also, ditto on Jimi's comment. Named parameters are much easier to read and spot an error in position than a string of ?.