# sql delete statements with multiple where condition error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-delete, sqlanywhere

is this the correct statement if not plz help me correct it.

```
String query = "delete from favourite where username=" + 
               Session["username"].ToString() + "and id=" + id;
```

Comment: No, this is not correct. You need to [use parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements).

Comment: **Always use parameterized sql and avoid string concatenation** to add values to sql statements. See [How can I add user-supplied input to an SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35163361/1260204), and [Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: so i have to use cmd,parameters.addwithvalue() and specify parameters there?

Comment: Follow instructions of [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7505842/22437); it does not use `AddWithValue` and specifically says to not use it.

Comment: i used AddWithValue() method and it worked. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is purely about SQL, then yes, what you have will work.  But, as you have it, you have a very serious security problem.  Google "SQL injection attacks".  I'm not sure what you are using for data access (ADO.NET? Entiry Framework?  Dapper?) But regardless, you'll want to use parameters:

```
var sql = "delete from favourite where username=@username and id=@id";
```

and then:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Session["username"].ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
```

But even then, `AddWithValue` isn't the best way, because it can cause type conversion issues once the query hits the database.  You are better off doing it longhand:

```
var userNameParam = new SqlParameter("username", SqlDbType.VarChar);
userNameParam.Value = Session["username"].ToString();

var idParam = new SqlParameter("id", SqlDbType.Int);
idParam .Value = id;

command.Parameters.Add(salaryParam);
command.Parameters.Add(idParam );
```

Comment: Thank You sir! It worked after using Parameters.AddWithValue() method.

Comment: You don't need to worry about SQL injection attacks if the input is not coming directly from the user or input is coming from something like a drop down list where values are controlled.

Comment: @DominicIsaia, I disagree.  Items in a dropdown list can easily be spoofed.  And even if the input is not coming "directly" from the user, it is almost ways going to come indirectly from a user, and the injection attack inputs are still possible.