# Unable to solve this exception when performing calculation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, desktop-application, windows-forms-designer

I have this code in textbox 2 which multiply the value of text box 1 and 2 adds the result to text box 3:

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text));
        }
```

When I insert the data in the database via this

```
code private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Receipts(Qty,ItemName,Price,Amount) values('" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();
            this.receiptsTableAdapter.Fill(this.shopDataSet.Receipts);
            textBox4.Clear();
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            textBox3.Clear();


            //MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted !");
        }
```

I get error on textBox2.Clear(); ( exceptional handling but data inserts succcessfully )
program is working fine without this,

```
textBox4.Clear();
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            textBox3.Clear();
```

I want to clear text boxes, i am only getting error on textbox2 which have the code to multiply the value of text box 1 and 2 adds the result to text box 3.

thanks :)

Comment: **Always use parameterized sql and avoid string concatenation** to add values to sql statements. This mitigates SQL Injection vulnerabilities and ensures values are passed to the statement correctly. See [How can I add user-supplied input to an SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35163361/1260204), and [Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: The exception is likely originating from `textBox2_TextChanged` and is likely a FormatException because you are trying to convert an empty string to an int. Debug your code to better understand how to trouble shoot exceptions and unexpected results.

Comment: i am not expert with debugging etc. Can you share the solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get error on textBox2.Clear(); ( exceptional handling but data inserts succcessfully ) program is working fine without this,

```
 textBox4.Clear();
 textBox1.Clear(); // This is the first problem
 textBox2.Clear(); // This is the second problem
 textBox3.Clear();
```

The reason for this error is because of the event `textBox2_TextChanged`. Inside you are trying to use the `Text` property to perform a calculation, this fails because the `Text` property is empty and it fails to convert it.

```
 textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text));
```

To fix this, you can check first, if the `Text` property can be successfully parsed before using it using the [Int.TryParse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) along with an out variable; only available targeting `C# >= 7.0`. For example:

```
 private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if(int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out int txt1) && int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out int txt2))
    {
       textBox3.Text = (txt1 * txt2).ToString();
    }
 }
```

Another version you could perhaps use if targeting versions older than C# 7.0:

```
 private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    int txt1;
    int txt2;
    if(int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out txt1) && int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out txt2))
    {
       textBox3.Text = (txt1 * txt2).ToString();
    }
 }
```

Comment: this code showing red underline under
txt , int1, int2

Comment: Under what code, there's no `int1` or `int2` in the code above. Do you mean `txt1` and or `txt2`? If so, you may be using an older version of `c#`, I'll update code.

Comment: under **txt1** and **txt2** and **int**

Comment: cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

Comment: Or rather than trying to do a `TryParse` you could just check `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty() )` and then try to parse your int.

Comment: Thanks :), can you please explain what i was doing wrong and what you did to solve the error 

again thank you very much, it was my first time here!

Comment: @Frank `Or rather than trying to do a TryParse you could just check if(string.IsNullOrEmpty() ) and then try to parse your int` why check if its null and or empty and then try and parse it? There's no need to do this because `TryParse` does this for you.

Comment: @Shehrooz Please see my second paragraph in my post. Basically calling `clear` on the textbox control clears the `Text` property and then fires that event off, when it does, the `Text` property is empty and it fails to convert that `Text` property to an int, so it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, the issue you're having is related to `textBox2_TextChanged` this `void` is getting called everytime that you change anything in `textBox2`.

In my opinion you should be checking your textbox(s) to make sure that they are not empty, and then try to parse your ints.

Here's something to get you started.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/lyNnQY

Comment: I'm sorry, but the fiddle isn't correct. They are not adding values, checking if the `Text` properties are null and or empty isn't needed as the `TryParse` will take care of this; this step isn't needed.

Comment: `TryParse` will return a `bool` back. The only reason I would be doing it this way is for better error handling. If you use `TryParse` and your textbox is empty, it will return false. If your textbox is not empty, and you have a invalid value; it will also return false. My approach is to check `NullOrEmpty` so the user then has a chance to validate the input and convert to an `int`, if it's not valid return a different error message. It's different, not wrong.

Comment: `so the user then has a chance to validate the input and convert to an int` of course and I would agree *if that's what the user is doing*, but they are not. What about the fiddle calculation?