# How can i change Date format in C# (DatePicker)?

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin.forms

I created a format with a date. It's XML code is very easy:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="data" Grid.Row="4" TextColor="Silver" MinimumDate="12/12/1900"/>
```

But I need to save this date in SQL, but the format is wrong. The format of SQL is yyy-mm-gg while the format of datepicker is mm-gg-yyyy.

How can i change this?
thanks a lot

Comment: A date is a date regardless of how you format it in the UI. Store it as a `DATE` in the database and you're all set.

Comment: @mm8 
I did, but it gives me the error because they are formed by DATA of sql and datepicker are different

Comment: Then you are inserting the value into the database the wrong way.

Comment: Show us the code where you store the date on the database

Comment: int result = db.QueryInserimento("INSERT INTO thewishlist.user(data) VALUES(''"+data.Date+"')");

Comment: Use parameters...

Comment: in which sense?

Comment: @Alessia: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A date is always a date regardless of how you format it in the UI.

You should store the value as a `DATE` in the database and retrieve it from the `DatePicker` using the `Date` property. It returns a `DateTime` that you should insert into the database using a parameter.

Please read the following regarding how and why to use parameters in your SQL statements:

[How can I add user-supplied input to an SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163361/how-can-i-add-user-supplied-input-to-an-sql-statement)

You may format a `DateTime` programmatically using the `ToString` method overload that accepts a format string:

```
data.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```