# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'Judgment'.'

Tags: c#

I can't find out why I'm getting this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'Judgment'.'

Code:

```
protected void gvComic_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    int ID = Convert.ToInt32(gvComic.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    string Name = ((TextBox)(gvComic.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
    string UnitPrice = ((TextBox)(gvComic.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text;
    string PublishCountry = ((TextBox)(gvComic.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0])).Text;
    string Author = ((TextBox)(gvComic.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Controls[0])).Text;
    string Description = ((TextBox)(gvComic.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Controls[0])).Text;
    string Translator = ((TextBox)(gvComic.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Controls[0])).Text;
    string CoverPage = ((TextBox)(gvComic.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Controls[0])).Text;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Comics SET Name='" + Name + "', UnitPrice='" + UnitPrice + "', PublishCountry='" + PublishCountry + "', Author='" + Author + "', Description='" + Description + "', Translator='" + Translator + "',CoverFile='" + CoverPage + "'  WHERE CId='" + ID + "'", conn);            

        int t = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (t > 0 )
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Data has updated!')</script>");
            gvComic.EditIndex = -1;
            BindGrind();
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVL96.png)

Comment: Let me guess: One input is like `Judgement's Day`? Always escape your user input!! Use prepared statements for that. Don't patch together your queries like that.

Comment: SQL injection is happy about your code. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: [Why is SQL Injection still a thing?](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2020/07/16/back-to-basics-sql-injection/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add user-supplied input to an SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163361/how-can-i-add-user-supplied-input-to-an-sql-statement)

Answer (score 1):

So the reason for this error is that you've broken your query string into several parts and when value comes with some unexpected or special character, it breaks the query string.

**Here is a much cleaner and safer way to do it**

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Comics SET Name=@name, UnitPrice=@unit, PublishCountry=@pubcontry, Author=@author, Description=@desc, Translator=@trans,CoverFile=@cfile  WHERE CId=@id", conn)
           
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cfile",CoverPage);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trans",Translator);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc",Description);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author",Author);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unit",UnitPrice);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",Name);
            
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

So in this way you write your query in a single string and define a @key wherever you want to insert a value in your query. and provide the value of key like this:

```
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key",value)
```

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)