# No errors in the code, but no changes occur in the table when trying to update it

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm trying to update my data in C# Win Form.
I created a button "update", but whenever I run it, I don't see any changes in the table and any occurring errors

```
void insertdata() {
    cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM airport";
    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    table.Clear();
    adapter.Fill(table);
    dgv.DataSource = table;
}

private void button_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE airport SET  p_name = '"+textBox2.Text+ "',p_age = '" + textBox3.Text + "', c_name = '" + textBox4.Text + "', date = '" + textBox5.Text + "', city_t = '" + textBox6.Text + "', city_f ='" + textBox7.Text + "', trip_num = '" + textBox8.Text + "', plane_type = '" + textBox9.Text+"' WHERE p_id = '"+textBox1+"'";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    insertdata();
}
```

I've tried to add

```
connection.Open();
connection.Close();
```

However, I keep getting: "System.InvalidOperationException: "The connection was not closed. The connection is open."

Could there be any change in my code for updating the rows in the table, as whenever I run it I don't get any errors.

Comment: This is because a connection is already open. The connection was not closed after update and it is again opened for select probably. Can you post the code where connection is opened and closed?

Comment: Every time you want to run some SQL, then `new` up a connection, open it and dispose it when you are done. That will solve 98% of your problems. Then read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection . Then name your textboxes with meaningful names.

Comment: @T.kowshikYedida connection.Open();
            cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE airport SET  p_name = '"+textBox2.Text+ "',p_age = '" + textBox3.Text + "', c_name = '" + textBox4.Text + "', date = '" + textBox5.Text + "', city_t = '" + textBox6.Text + "', city_f ='" + textBox7.Text + "', trip_num = '" + textBox8.Text + "', plane_type = '" + textBox9.Text+"' WHERE p_id = '"+textBox1+"'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            insertdata();
            connection.Close();

Comment: (Possible) side note: Do not use string interpolation or concatenation to get values into SQL queries. That's error prone and might make your program vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Use parameterized queries. See ["How can I add user-supplied input to an SQL statement?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163361/how-can-i-add-user-supplied-input-to-an-sql-statement).

Comment: @qrttttt If you follow my advice the problem will stop.

Comment: As a debug step: what exactly *is* that CommandText that you are trying to execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note the you wrote

```
WHERE p_id = '"+textBox1+"'
```

Instead of

```
WHERE p_id = '"+textBox1.Text+"'
```

Probably you don't have an ID that equals to the textBox...