# Update XML column in T-SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, t-sql

I want to replace part of an xslt file stored in a `xml` column in a SQL Server database table.

I tried updating the entire column value using a syntax like below

```
UPDATE myTable
SET myColumn = '<user>
  <user_id>1</user_id>
  <fname>Josef</fname>
  <lname>Brown</lname>
  <email_>jo0@adventure-works.com</email_>
</user>'
WHERE id = 1
```

but since it has single and double quotes strewn all over the place, it doesn't work (SQL query parsing itself fails).

Is there a C# verbatim string equivalent in T-SQL?

If yes, then too easy, otherwise,

I probably have to search for my particular element which looks like below

```
  <div class="someClass">
    <div class="someOtherClass">
      <xsl:if test="SomeElement/ChildElement='NULL'">
```

and replace it with

```
  <div class="someClass">
    <div class="someOtherClass">
      <xsl:if test="SomeElement/ChildElement=''">
```

Basically, just replace NULL in the xsl:if element with an empty string

How do I do that? Any help appreciated.

Comment: `it doesn't work` can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: by 'it doesn't work', I meant sql query parsing fails

Comment: Do not use string interpolation or concatenation to get values into SQL queries. That's error prone and might make your program vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Use parameterized queries. See ["How can I add user-supplied input to an SQL statement?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163361/how-can-i-add-user-supplied-input-to-an-sql-statement). And do it properly, mind that ["AddWithValue is Evil"](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). [`SqlDataType`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.sqldatatype?view=sql-smo-160) lists `Xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found and replaced all occurrences of one single quote with two single quotes in the xml value - that way got my sql to parse fine and then used this syntax to update the row.

```
UPDATE myTable
SET myColumn = '<user>
  <user_id>1</user_id>
  <fname>Caroline</fname>
  <lname>O''Connor</lname>
  <email_>jo0@adventure-works.com</email_>
</user>'
WHERE id = 1
```