# c# ms access date input wrong format

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

In my program i input a  record to MS Access database like this

```
INSERT INTO Stock VALUES('"+ textCode.Text +"', '#"+ datetimepickerDate.Value +"#', somenumber)
```

With datetimepicker.Value says 09/06/2022 19:35:14

But for some reason when i open MS Access and checked the record, the date magicaly turns 06/09/2022 19:35:14

I didn't change the datetimepicker's format and it should use system date format, and now i can't select or update the record because of the day and the month switches place.

It works without a problem on my PC, but it wont do with my one specific friend's.

How do i fix this?

Thanks~

Answer (score 2):

Here: `'#"+ datetimepickerDate.Value +"#'` the following happens:

- `datetimepickerDate.Value` returns a `DateTime`.
- That `DateTime` is used in string concatenation, which causes an implicit conversion to `string`, **using your system date format** (`09/06/2022`, dd/mm/yyyy).
- You add a hash in front and in the back (`#09/06/2022#`). Now it's a string containing an "MS Access date literal".

The problem is that MS Access date literals are **always** in the format mm/dd/yyyy. Thus, your day and month value may get "switched", depending on the user's system date format.

---

Solution: Don't use string concatenation for SQLs, use parameterized SQL instead:

- [How can I add user-supplied input to an SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35163361/87698)

Example:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO Stock VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, myDbConnection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", textCode.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", datetimepickerDate.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", somenumber);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```