# How to show image from database in a UserControl added to a FlowLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, image, winforms

Open Dialogbox for selecting image

```
string filePath;
Byte[] imageByteArray;

private void btnBrows_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
  ofd.Filter = "Images(.jpg, .png)|* .png; *.jpg";

  if(ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    filePath = ofd.FileName;
    txtPictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(filePath);
  }
}
```

Save image in database:

```
try
{
  Image temp = new Bitmap(txtPictureBox.Image);
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  temp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
  imageByteArray = ms.ToArray();
                
  DataTable dt = ConnectionClass.Selectcommand("select max(CatID) from category");
        
  ConnectionClass.InsertCommand("insert into products values('" + txtProductName.Text + "','" + txtPrice.Text + "','" + dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() + "','" + imageByteArray + "')");
   MessageBox.Show("Data saved successfully");
   comboAddProduct.SelectedIndex = -1;
   txtPictureBox.Image = null;
}
catch(Exception ex) 
{
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

[image]

Now how to read this image in flowLayout using userControl method?

Comment: Note: you have to learn to use parameters for your sql calls to avoid sql injection.  See [How can I add user-supplied input to an SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35163361/719186)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution transforming the Byte Array retrieved from the database into an image and showing it in a DataGridView in a column of type DataGridViewImageColumn:

**I created a class that simulates the database entity, here called "GridData":**

```
public class GridData
 {
   public string pID { get; set; }
   public string pName { get; set; }
   public Image pImage { get; set; }
 }
```

**I created a Data Source for the GridView with the entity class:**
[image]

**In the code, I just retrieve the Byte Array from the database (simulating through the same code you used to insert), and fill in the object that will make up the DataGridView list:**

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();


Image imageBD = GetImageFromDataBase();


List<GridData> data = new List<GridData>() 
        { new GridData() 
            { 
                pID = "1", pName = "Name1", pImage = imageBD 
            } 
        };
dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
}

private Image GetImageFromDataBase()
{
  // Simulate getting image from database
  Image temp = new Bitmap("C:\\Teste.jpg");
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  temp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);


  // Database field with bytearray image
  byte[] imageByteArray = ms.ToArray();


  // Convert bytearray to image
  using (MemoryStream memstr = new MemoryStream(imageByteArray))
   {
      Image img = Image.FromStream(memstr);
      return img;
    }
 }
```

**result:**

[image]